# Python list comprehension include index on dict

Tags: python

I have a *list* of *dicts*

```
l = [
  {
     "k1": "v1",
  },
  {
     "k2": "v2",
  }
]
```

I want to update this list with the index of each entry, like this

```
[
  {
     "index": 0,
     "k1": "v1",
  },
  {
     "index": 1,
     "k2": "v2",
  }
]
```

How can I do this using list comprehension?

Comment: Why isn't the implicit array index sufficient?

Comment: Because it is dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `i` as the counter for `enumerate` and `j` as the dict, which you can unpack in the new dictionary.

```
l2 = [{'index' : i, **j} for i,j in enumerate(l)]
print(l2)
```

Or as @Martijn Pieters, a python 3.9 solution:

```
[{"index": i} & j for i, j in enumerate(l)]
```

Comment: In Python 3.9 and up you can also use the `&` operator to combine dictionaries: `[{"index": i} & j for i, j in enumerate(l)]`. Not a big win _here_ but something to consider.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! I haven't yet updated to python 3.9 because it had caused problems previously. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutable method `update` here, iterating  the list with `enumerate`:

```py
for idx,d in enumerate(l):
    d.update(index=idx)
    
>>> l
[{'k1': 'v1', 'index': 0}, {'k2': 'v2', 'index': 1}]
```